# Why isn't my detail view reflecting my selection?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I'm learning iOS development and reading through Apple's tutorials (namely "Your Second iOS App") and building a Bird Watching app. Long story short, it's a list of birds, you select the bird in the table view and it segues to a new view showing more details about the bird.

Everything seems to work, but after segueing the new view doesn't get filled in. It's empty.

I thought it might be in my `prepareForSegue:` method, but it does get fired as I put an NSLog in there for a test.

Here's the `prepareForSegue:` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailViewSegue"]) {
        CSBirdDetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        CSBirdSighting *selectedBirdSighting = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];

        detailViewController.birdSighting = selectedBirdSighting;
        detailViewController.birdNameLabel.text = @"Stinker";
        NSLog(@"HEY THERE!");
    }
}
```

Here's the Xcode project in its entirety (rather small) for further information: http://cl.ly/37041I2K0N24

I just can't figure out why it won't display. With the method above I'm setting the destinationViewController's (the detail view's) data from the model (a separate class used by the master view/source view controller). The data I set is a BirdSighting object essentially that the class then reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing

```
[self configureView];
```

in your CSBirdDetailViewController viewDidLoad method instead of the prepareForSeque: method

The prepareForSegue: method is too early to do the configure of the view.

The view is created when the view is first accessed (lazy loading). It is not created when the CSBirdDetailViewController is first initiated.

Comment: It's not in the prepareForSegue: method, though.

Comment: Shouldn't my random text in the segue changing the name to "Stinker" (yeah...) still work, though?

Comment: detailViewController.birdSighting = selectedBirdSighting; - this line is in the prepareForSegue - this line will call the setBirdSighting: method which calls [self configureView];

Comment: No, because the view has not been created, so the label is nil. Try placing this before the Stinker line:         NSLog(@"label: %@", detailViewController.birdNameLabel); - this will result in showing that the birdNameLabel is null

Comment: Sorry, still a newb here, but what exactly do you mean by hasn't been configured yet? Also, that suggestion worked perfectly. Why in Apple's tutorial do they do it in the way I had previously? (Found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH5-SW6 under To implement the configureView method.)

Comment: I meant "created" not "configured" - sorry - I edited it. I hadn't seen that Apple example, but if you look at the final code, it does have [self configureView]; in their viewDidLoad method.

Comment: The reason you need it in the set as well, is because viewDidLoad is only called when the view is first loaded - if you subsequently call the view again, it needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Ah, thank you! So it needs to be in viewDidLoad because if you just call it in set, even though it's about to segue to it, it hasn't been created yet so when it access the labels they won't exist yet? And when I call the set method subsequently it will have been created, so it's all good? Am I understanding correctly? :D

Comment: Yes - that's about right, as long as your "it's about to segue to it, it hasn't been created yet" means that the view controller is created in the prepareToSegue, but the view controller's view is not created until it is needed.